# What is "dimen" in the documentation for the ifthen package?

Tags: documentation, dimensions, conditionals

In the [documentation for the `ifthen` package](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.ifi.uio.no/it/latex-links/ifthen.pdf), there is a test called `\lengthtest` which compares two *`<dimen>`* parameters with the operators `<`, `>` or `=`. (For other test commands, *`<dimen>`* is usually *`<string>`* or *`<number>`*.) Searching for "dimen" in the document and on google, I find nothing to explain what it means.

What is *`<dimen>`*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AFAIK, this would be referring to a *length*, so, either 1pt, 2cm, 5mm, 10em, etc. or previously defined lengths: \textwidth, \parskip, 4\itemsep, etc.

This would come in handy, for example, if you want to do one thing if the length of your title is larger than the width of the page, and a different thing if it is smaller than it...

Comment: Makes sense, now that you say it...

Comment: DEK originally used *<dimen>*; Leslie Lamport changed the name to *<length>*.

Comment: `\parskip` and `\itemsep` are both skips, not dimensions.

Answer (score 10):

Quoting from Donald E. Knuth, *The TeXbook*, pages 59, 61:

> Henceforth we shall use the term `<dimen>` to stand for a legitimate TeX dimension. [...] [A] complete definition of everything that a `<dimen>` can be will be given in Chapter 24.

My (hopefully educated) guess is that this is what the `ifthen` documentation refers to.